# WindowsPhone 8 （A jump to another application

Tags: windows-phone-8

WindowsPhone 8 （A jump to another application 
）
I want to in my applications to invoke other applications, the application I don't know any news, just know the name, how do I use

. Await the Windows System. The Launcher. LaunchUriAsync (new Uri (" wechat: "));

"Wechat" should be placed here called program I want to use

Comment: Sorry, you can't launch an external app just by knowing its name.

Comment: Can you tell how to deal with thanks

Comment: KooKizYou can be a little more than hints for this question I really more than a week more tips, please thank you

Comment: What hint? I told you it's not possible. The only way is to register a custom URI scheme in the third-party application, as explained by David Bekham in his answer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Launching apps that you’ve publishedIEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
apps.First().Launch(string.Empty);

Comment: This method can not.. I tried this method but it jump to themselves, a specific Id it if I don't jump to a specified lower this way please..

Answer (score 0):

First you have to write the following protocol in the `WMAppManifest.xml` under the Extensions tag. Thereafter you can launch your app from any other apps with the specified protocol name using `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` method.

```
<Protocol Name="webchat" NavUriFragment="LaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_Default"/>
```

For further clarification you can refer the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: No (<Protocol Name="webchat" NavUriFragment="LaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_Default"/>
), the third party applications is the ( <Extensions>
      <Extension ExtensionName="Photos_Extra_Share" ConsumerID="{5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5632}" TaskID="_default" />
    </Extensions>)